# How to remove marker after map is recreated?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

Based on the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getId%28%29), marker objects will not persist across restoration from Bundle objects. So, is there anyway to identify the markers after being restored, so that the markers can be removed later on?

Am I understanding the documentation wrong, is there an error on the documentation, or there is simply no way to remove markers after the original object have been destroyed?

Comment: but the document saying that __"When a map is restored from a Bundle, markers that were on that map are also restored"__ and __"A marker's id can be used to retrieve the new instance of a Marker object after such restoration."__

Comment: @KunalK, "A marker's id can be used to retrieve the new instance of a Marker object after such restoration.", but how? There doesn't seem to be any way to do it. Which class or method should be used?

Comment: Documentation is wrong here. There are couple of related to this API bugs raised for Android team. None of those is resolved by now. I suppose the only way to go is to clear old markers and re-add them after map is being restored...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to identify Markers as they are NOT persisted and NOT restored. The documentation is wrong and hopefully they will change (fix) the documentation and not add persistance of markers.

Comment: Is there any proof or any other documentation or reference to show this?

Comment: Sure. See the second comment under my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15614435/2183804